# Need to add a class name dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, swiper.js

Currently i am using swipper carousel in the website that i m creating.I would like to add some animation to the caption of each sliding image.So i m using @-webkit-keyframes for it.But only for the first image i m getting this effect.In other Images the content is static.Any idea how to implement this for every slide after it loads.Appreciate any help.Thanks...

```
     .carousel-content{
            width: 1200px;
            height: 100px;
         //padding: 20px;
           padding-top:200px;
           padding-left:80px;
           padding-right: 80px;
           position: absolute;
           text-align: center;
           color:white;
           font-size:40px;
           font-weight: 800;
           -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
           animation-duration: 2s;
          -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
           animation-fill-mode: both;
     }
   @-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
            0% {
               opacity: 0;
               -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
            }
            100% {
               opacity: 1;
               -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            }
         }

         @keyframes fadeInDown {
            0% {
               opacity: 0;
               transform: translateY(-20px);
            }
            100% {
               opacity: 1;
               transform: translateY(0);
            }
         }

      .fadeInDown {
             -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown ;
              animation-name: fadeInDown ;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="swiper-container" >
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" >
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown ">
           Buisness is good 
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown ">
            Buisness is good 
        </div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
           <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown">
           Buisness is good 
        </div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown">
           Buisness is good 
        </div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" >
           <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown">
            Buisness is good 
        </div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
           <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown">
            Buisness is good 
        </div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

My jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/2ume828d/

Comment: can you provide your code as a snippet

Comment: First of all remove extra `"` from your html. What is this `class="carousel-content" "fadeInDown"`?

Comment: ok give me a minute..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, there are callback functions available for swiper slider, you can use them to toggle `fadeInDown` class.

```js
    var sliderContents = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-content');
      function removeEffect(){
       sliderContents.forEach(function(sliderContent){
          sliderContent.classList.remove('fadeInDown');
        })
      }
      //removeEffect();
      var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        slidesPerView: 1,
        paginationClickable: true,
        loop: true,
        autoplay:4000, 
        spaceBetween: 0,
        centeredSlides: true,
        onTransitionStart: function(slider){
         removeEffect();
          var activeSlider =  document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-active > .carousel-content ');
         activeSlider.classList.add('fadeInDown');
        },
    });
```

```css
 html, body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #eee;
       -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Lato",Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.66667;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #333333;
    margin:0px;
    }
    .swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;
        
        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .carousel-content{
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 
  position: absolute;
//  top: 50%;
text-align: center;
color:black;
font-size:40px;
font-weight: 800;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
   @-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
            0% {
               opacity: 0;
               -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
            }
            100% {
               opacity: 1;
               -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            }
         }
         
         @keyframes fadeInDown {
            0% {
               opacity: 0;
               transform: translateY(-20px);
            }
            100% {
               opacity: 1;
               transform: translateY(0);
            }
         }
    
         .fadeInDown {
            -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
            animation-name: fadeInDown;
         }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Swiper Slider</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="swiper-container" >
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" >
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="carousel-content first">
           Buisness 1
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="carousel-content">
            Buisness 2
        </div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
           <div class="carousel-content">
           Buisness 3
        </div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="carousel-content">
           Buisness 4
        </div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" >
           <div class="carousel-content">
            Buisness 5
        </div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
           <div class="carousel-content">
            Buisness 6
        </div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.min.js">
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Check the documentation, maybe you would be able to add effect using available apis.
http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the absolute positioning to make visible what happens. As you can see, the animation works for all the different elements at the same time. Therefore when moving to the next slide, it looks as if it is static. You need to add class `fadeInDown` dynamically when the new slide is shown.

```css
.carousel-content {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.fadeInDown {
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown ">
        Buisness is good
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown ">
        Buisness is good
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown">
        Buisness is good
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown">
        Buisness is good
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown">
        Buisness is good
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="carousel-content fadeInDown">
        Buisness is good
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```